# How can i use the separate function to clean data that has multiple conditions?

Tags: r, data-science

I'M trying to clean some data with using separate the problem is that I have multiple conditions I have to account for plus how do i make sure that the addresses that are correct are not affected. For example one address is correct but changes it.

````
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
EAC<- read_excel("EmpressAddressCleanup_20200817.xlsx")
av<-select(EAC,`Addr 1`,`Addr 2`,City,State,Country)%>%
    separate("Addr 1", c("Address 2","address 1"), sep = "[-]")```
````

Comment: Please include your data so your question can be answered. Guidance for writing a good question can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.